# TFTPD Failing with "unknown option -?"

Tags: debian, tftp

I am trying to run a PXE server on VM and another client on another VM for testing. I am using `tftpd-hpa` to host a tftp server. This is failing with the following error :

```
unknown option -?
...
Failed t start LSB: HPA's tftp server.
```

This is the output of `systemctl status tftpd.service`.

My config is the default one -

```
TFTP_USERNAME="tftp"
TFTP_DIRECTORY="/srv/tftp"
TFTP_ADDRESS="0.0.0.0:69"
TFTP_OPTIONS="--secure"
```

I have checked that the directory is created.

I am not able to figure out what is wrong. Please help.